# WINAPI Event Object unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, winapi, process, synchronization, deadlock

I have 2 programs.
The first program will open the second one and will also create 2 Event objects that will be used for synchronization.
The second one (the one to be opened) will open those 2 Event objects.
Both of the programs will run a for loop to simulate writing and reading operations from memory.

Program one:

```
    read = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, "READ");
    write = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, "WRITE");

    CreateProcess("PATH_TO_EXE", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, 0, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        printf("Wrote data to memory\n");
        SetEvent(write);
        WaitForSingleObject(read, INFINITE);
    }
```

Program two:

```
    HANDLE read, write;

    read = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, false, "READ");
    write = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, false, "WRITE");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(write, INFINITE);
        printf("Read data from memory.\n");
        SetEvent(read);
    }
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
Wrote data to memory.
Read data from memory.
Wrote data to memory.
Read data from memory.
       ....
```

but the real output is something like:

```
Wrote data to memory.
Read data from memory.
Read data from memory.
Read data from memory.
Read data from memory.
Read data from memory.
Read data from memory.
Read data from memory.
Wrote data to memory.
Read data from memory.
Wrote data to memory.
Wrote data to memory.
Read data from memory.
      ...
```

And at some point it just hangs, which would mean a deadlock. But I'm not sure how is this possible. Any help?

Comment: `EVENT_MODIFY_STATE | SYNCHRONIZE` must be. the `WaitForSingleObject(write, INFINITE);` always failed with error access denied, but you not check this

Comment: and in case child process - you can instead create named events - make handles inheritable and pass it values in command line to child

Comment: Suggestion: Add `fflush(stdout);` after both `printf` calls.

Comment: @RbMm can you post your coment as an aswer? I want to mark it as a solution. It help solving the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) - handle to the object (1-st parameter) must have the `SYNCHRONIZE` access right. otherwise api failed with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. but you call

```
write = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, false, "WRITE");
```

requested access not include `SYNCHRONIZE` which you need and include `EVENT_MODIFY_STATE` which you really not need in this code. so you need change code to

```
write = OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, false, "WRITE");
```

also you not check result of any api call. if you do this - you just view that `WaitForSingleObject(write, INFINITE);` return `WAIT_FAILED` and `GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

also if you need ipc via this 2 events with child process - better create it unnamed and inherited, and pass it values via command line to child. if you want test only event work logic - more easy use separate thread instead new process. for this test code can look like:

```
ULONG WINAPI child(void* p)
{
    if (HANDLE read = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, false, L"READ"))
    {
        if (HANDLE write = OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, false, L"WRITE"))
        {
            ULONG i = (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)p;
            do 
            {
                if (WaitForSingleObject(write, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED){
                    DbgPrint("2:%u\n", GetLastError());
                    break;
                }
                DbgPrint("Read data from memory.\n");
                if (!SetEvent(read)){
                    DbgPrint("3:%u\n", GetLastError());
                    break;
                }
            } while (--i);

            CloseHandle(write);
        }
        CloseHandle(read);
    }
    return 0;
}

void bfg()
{
    if (HANDLE read = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, L"READ"))
    {
        if (HANDLE write = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, L"WRITE"))
        {
            ULONG i = 16;

            if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, child, (PVOID)(ULONG_PTR)i, 0, 0))
            {
                do 
                {
                    DbgPrint("Wrote data to memory\n");
                    if (!SetEvent(write) || WaitForSingleObject(read, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED){
                        DbgPrint("1:%u\n", GetLastError());
                        break;
                    }
                } while (--i);

                WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

                CloseHandle(hThread);
            }

            CloseHandle(write);
        }
        CloseHandle(read);
    }
}
```

interesting that early (before win 8.1) was *EventPair* object in windows, which was design for such task. but unknown reason it was removed

Comment: I removed any code that wasn't relevant to my problem. I wasn't aware though that WaitForSingleObject could point me that information.